# how to setup browsersync in production server

Tags: laravel, vue.js, webpack, production-environment, browser-sync

im new in laravel and vue. i've been trying to use browsersync in server but no luck. successfully setup in my local but when i try to set in server its just not working. so i want my website to auto reload when there is new component update on server and im using cloudflare to purge new update after push to git and pull to server. can anyone give me a example to setup in production server? if its only possible for local dev, any suggestion about it? sorry for bad english.

my code now in webpack.mix.js

```
mix.browserSync({
open: false,
files: [
 'app/**/*',
 'public/**/*',
 'resources/views/**/*',
 'routes/**/*'
]
})
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js').sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

and this in my blade

```
@if (getenv('APP_ENV') === 'local')
<script id="__bs_script__">//<![CDATA[
    document.write("<script async src='http://HOST/browser-sync/browser-sync-client.js?v=2.18.6'><\/script>".replace("HOST", location.hostname));
    //]]>
</script>
@endif
```

thanks for your help sensei!

Comment: https://laravel-mix.com/docs/5.0/browsersync it will work only in `npm run watch` this cmd

Comment: You should not use browsersync in production as that would use a lot of memory and cost a lot more. In production should all be static, `npm run prod`

Comment: @DevinGray thanks for your information. any suggestion to implement auto update component on production server using laravel vue? i just thinking to use firebase but i want to try using another implementation

Comment: @KamleshPaul yeah its work in local but in server not. thanks

Comment: `npm run prod` generate new `app.js` it contained all the component so when you update that code in server you will get all the new components and all the thing

Comment: It is a bad idea to auto run this on production server, you should initiate a new build every time something changes. I am not sure what you want to build or what is meant by component is "changed" but if you are coding locally and want that to reflect on production you should deploy it with a npm run prod task

Comment: @DevinGray i mean any suggestion to auto update component in production server using another way? like there is a modal popup message that tell user about new updates in website every login if there is new update and when user click ok refresh page and update new pull component. right now user need to ctrl+shift+r to get new application content after push updated component to server and i want to make it auto update

Comment: use mix.version() then it will clear cache, I think you would benefit from a few tutorials and info regarding this.

Comment: @DevinGray so still using laravel mix? okay then thanks sensei